# Check if wireless-tools is installed or not in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, apt, wifi

i want to check if `wireless-config` (for `iwconfig`) is installed on the system (debian). If not, then install this with `apt-get`. My bash script looks like this:

```
if ! hash wireless-tools 2>/dev/null; then
   apt-get install wireless-tools; 
else
   echo "wireless-tools is installed"
fi
```

The big problem: `hash wireless-tools` seems not to work. There is never anything to return, either if wireless-tools is installed or not. How can i check for this in a different way?

Comment: Are you looking for the _package being installed_ or are you looking for the _binary being present_?  These are two different questions (which admittedly should have a fairly expansive overlap).

Comment: Just for the package being installed.

Comment: but a quick question: where is the difference of an installed package and just present binary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest `type` over `hash` for checking the binary.  However, there is also a tool specifically designed for checking the state of packages:

```
if ! dpkg-query -s wireless-tools 1> /dev/null 2>&1 ; then
    echo "Package wireless-tools is not currently installed."
else
    echo "Package wireless-tools is currently installed."
fi
```

Comment: ``dpkg-query`` is exactly what i need. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it.  Welcome to U&L!  If this answer met your needs, please mark it as 'accepted' so that other folks know you are no longer seeking an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want `iwconfig`, the more sustainable long-term solution (say, if you were to switch package manager or distribution) is to check for the binary that you actually want to use. You can do this POSIXly using `command -v`:

```
if command -v iwconfig >/dev/null; then
    echo 'iwconfig present'
else
    echo 'iwconfig absent'
fi
```

From `help command` in bash:

> command: command [-pVv] command [arg ...]
>
> Execute a simple command or display information about commands.
>
> Runs COMMAND with ARGS suppressing  shell function lookup, or display
>   information about the specified COMMANDs.  Can be used to invoke commands
>   on disk when a function with the same name exists.
>
> Options:
>
> [...]
>
> - -v    print a description of COMMAND similar to the `type' builtin